# Multiple shared cascading combobox component in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I create a component for managing **cascading** country and state. If I put only one country and one state to form, everything is working perfectly. But, when I put three country and state, then everything is corrupting like below example. How can I achieve this?

**One country-state (working example)**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdqtha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Three country-state (NOT working example)**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5xpny?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: You have an unique element, Are you looking for FormArray? https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Comment: My main problem is cascading combobox. When I select first `country`, both first and second `state`, filling. But I want only filling first `state` @Eliseo.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your problem? I don't see what issue you are actually having. What specifically do you want have happen? What are you trying to do?

Comment: My main problem is cascading combobox. When I select first country, both first and second state, filling. But I want only filling first state  And also when I submit form, I want correct values. @ColbyHunter

Comment: So you need a form that is going to let you have multiple **separate** country/state values? And if so, is it specifically only two country/state options or will there be potential for someone to submit say... three?

Comment: Yes. It can be more than two country/state. It's dynamic.You can think form like, my country/state, my father's country/state and my mother's country/state in one form. @ColbyHunter

Comment: Okay, so we need to get really specific here. Can a single person have more than one country/state? Or is it one country/state per person?

Comment: I edited my second NOT WORKİNG stackblitz. Can you check it? My main purpose is work that example.  And lastly submit the form. You can see from that stackblitz that, if I change student country then morher's and father's state filling. But, I don't want this. And then I can't submit it. Because they don't have any 'id'. So, I don't want taking their value when I submit the form. @ColbyHunter

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution @ColbyHunter . I added stackblitz link to below `RomaRuzich`'s answer as comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two elements that have reference to same variables:

```
<app-country [studentForm]="studentForm"></app-country>
<app-state [studentForm]="studentForm"></app-state>

<br/><br/>

<app-country [studentForm]="studentForm"></app-country>
<app-state [studentForm]="studentForm"></app-state>
```

Each of components have access to same property of studentForm class. If you want that component group filled separately then you have to write something like:

```
app.component.ts:

 this.studentForm = new FormGroup({
  'studentName':new FormControl(''),
  'countryId1': new FormControl(''),
  'stateId1': new FormControl(''),
  'countryId2': new FormControl(''),
  'stateId2': new FormControl('')
})
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-country [studentForm]="studentForm" [id]="'countryId1'"></app-country>
<app-state [studentForm]="studentForm" [id]="'stateId1'" [countryId]="'countryId1'"></app-state>

<br/><br/>

<app-country [studentForm]="studentForm" [id]="'countryId2'"></app-country>
<app-state [studentForm]="studentForm" [id]="'stateId2'" [countryId]="'countryId2'"></app-state>
```

And in your country and state components use countryId1/countryId2 and stateId1/stateId2 respectively (it is also need to modify country and state components to use 'id' parameter).

**UPDATE**

In country.component.ts add

```
@Input() id: string;
```

In state.component.ts add

```
@Input() id:string;
@Input() countryId:string;

get states(): State[]{
   var val = this.studentForm.controls[this.countryId].value;
   return this.selectService.filterStates(val);
};
```

In country/state.component.html change to:

```
<select [formControlName]="id">...
```

In select.service.ts change:

```
filterStates(countryId){
   if(!countryId) return null;
   return this.getStates().filter((item) => item.countryid == countryId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RomaRuzich. But how can I modify my component using for 'id' parameter? Because, I'm newbie at angular.

Comment: Read https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction about how you can send data between components. So, in child component (country/state component) you take parameter 'id' of type string. Then in country/state.component.html you at 'formControlName' pass value of  'id' parameter.

Comment: There is article https://medium.com/@mail.bahurudeen/create-a-dynamic-form-with-configurable-fields-and-validations-using-angular-6-994db56834da . It has to help you.

Comment: Thanks again @RomaRuzich. But these are very big documents. It's very difficult to know what and how to use.

Comment: I edited answer. But I would do this by another way. I would create component-wrapper for country/state components, and use it in app.component.

Comment: I did all of your said in this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-maxzyi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html  stackblitz link. But, there is something wrong. Can you check please? @RomaRuzich

Comment: Yes. It's my mistake. Thanks a lot for your helps @RomaRuzich. It worked perfectly. Perfectly working link is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-maxzyi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html